# MongoDB Replica Sets Not Syncing?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver, database-replication

I've been following the steps on the tutorial for deploying a replica set to a development/test environment: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/deploy-replica-set/#deploy-a-development-or-test-replica-set

I have three instances of mongod.exe running, and all three are able to connect properly.

I wanted to verify that the Secondaries are properly syncing up to the Primary when an Insert happens, but when I do an Insert, there doesn't seem to be any indication that the Secondaries are following through.

---

For instance, I have a MongoShell connected to the Primary and I run the commands:

```
db.createCollection("testCol")
db.testCol.insert( { item: "card", qty: 15 } )
```

This creates the 'testCol' collection and inserts a value into it.

When I do:

```
show collections
```

The 'testCol' collection shows up fine, and the item I inserted is present.

My question is:  **Shouldn't the Secondaries sync up with the Primary and copy the Collection and Item over?**

Starting up another MongoShell and connecting to one of the Secondaries, I see that the collection I created on the Primary is not showing up.

Am I just misunderstanding how Replica Sets work, or is there something else that I need to set in order for the Secondaries to copy Insert actions?

I followed the instructions in the link I gave in the beginning, so any configurations that I have set up are exactly the same.

Comment: Please post the output of `rs.status()`.'exactly the same' is tricky, since the sample has placeholders such as `<hostname>`. What is your hostname? It would be helpful if you posted the exact configuration. Also check your firewall settings (try to connect to each `mongod` from the console directly).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well that's embarrassing.

Turns out that I was looking at the incorrect database on my side.  The way that I'd configured, I needed to be using a database named `test` but I had been doing inserts on `local`.

Looking back at the setup instructions for Replica Sets, I'm not quite sure where I configured MongoShell to connect to `test`, but connecting to that database and making a change on the Primary seemed to fix everything.

---

Here's how my MongoShell connected to the Primary looked like:

```
MongoDB shell version: 2.4.5
connecting to: 127.0.0.1.27017/test
```

Maybe the connection to `test` was configured when I first set up MongoDB?  Not too sure right now.

---

Doing a little more looking around, it seems like when you connect with MongoShell, it's automatically connecting to the `test` database.  Not sure how to change parameters in the shortcut I'm using in order to have it point to a different database.

---

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/mongo-shell/#basic-shell-javascript-operations

> In the mongo shell, db is the variable that references the current
>   database. The variable is automatically set to the default database
>   test or is set when you use the use  to switch current database.

I guess this means there's no parameter you can pass in, and you have to do a `use <db>` manually?

---

Found it!

If you set up a shortcut to mongo.exe, set this as your Target:

```
C:\mongodb\bin\mongo.exe <db name> --host <host> --port <port>
```

Previously I only had the `--port` parameter, but adding in the rest allowed me to start directly in a specific database.